# AWS describe-images with filter to exclude by tag value

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ami

I'd like to find images in my account and exclude by tags with certain values.  For example, this below isn't allowed:

```
aws ec2 describe-images --owners self --filters "Name=tag:commit_hash_short,Values!=[5d6447e,c001fab]"
```

But the inverse does work:

```
aws ec2 describe-images --owners self --filters "Name=tag:commit_hash_short,Values=[5d6447e,c001fab]"
```

Is there a way to do this kind of operation?

Comment: No, you can't make negative queries. You have to get all images and then you filter them yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Marcin's advice, this works to exclude 1 value (MYCOMMITHASH) using jq, but I'm not sure how to change that to a list.

```
aws ec2 describe-images --owners self --query "Images[*].{ImageId:ImageId,commit_hash_short:[Tags[?Key=='commit_hash_short']][0][0].Value}" | jq 'del(.[] | select(.commit_hash_short == "MYCOMMITHASH"))'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `--queries` to get the output you are looking for. An example might be something like:

```
aws ec2 describe-images --owners self --query 'Images[?!not_null(Tags[?Key == `commit_hash_short` && Value == `5d6447e`])]' |jq -r '.[].ImageId'
```

I'm basing this response on my own similar efforts and articles like [this one](https://docs.rackspace.com/blog/how-to-use-the-aws-cli-to-find-untagged-instances/).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).